# UISegmentedControl won't change value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to create a `UISegmentedControl` programatically. I have a `UIViewController` in the storyboard with nothing in it.

.h file

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
NSString *feedBackButtonTitle;
NSString *contactsButtonTitle;
```

and here are the property declarations.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
-(void) segmentedControlIndexChanged;
```

In `viewDidLoad:` I have initalized and added the `UISegmentedControl`.

```
   NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([language isEqualToString:@"en"]){
    contactsButtonTitle = [[[configFileDictionary objectForKey:@"Contacts"] objectForKey:@"Label"] objectForKey:@"en"];
    feedBackButtonTitle = [[[[[configFileDictionary objectForKey:@"Contacts"] objectForKey:@"Contact"]objectForKey:@"Feedback"]objectForKey:@"Label"]objectForKey:@"en"];
}
else if([language isEqualToString:@"fr"]){
    contactsButtonTitle = [[[configFileDictionary objectForKey:@"Contacts"] objectForKey:@"Label"] objectForKey:@"fr"];
    feedBackButtonTitle = [[[[[configFileDictionary objectForKey:@"Contacts"] objectForKey:@"Contact"]objectForKey:@"Feedback"]objectForKey:@"Label"]objectForKey:@"fr"];

}
NSArray *itemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:contactsButtonTitle, feedBackButtonTitle, nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemsArray];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
//segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f,40.0f);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 //  [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

// Create view for contact display.
[self createViews];
```

and this the `(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged`

```
-(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            [self createViews];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self showFeedbackForm];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This is showing the segmented control on the screen just fine, but when I click on the options in the segmentedcontrol, it always goes into the option case 0. segmented control and opens `[self createViews];`

On inserting breakpoints at the line `case 0`, I noticed that the option _selectedSegment in segmentedControl is 1. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: segmentedControl and self.segmentedControl may not be connected, check it.

Comment: I am doing everything programatically. In the storyboard, there is an empty ViewController. So there is nothing to connect.

Comment: check if segmentedControl == self.segmentedControl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I created in my `UIViewController` a property `segmentedControl` and then wrote only that code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *itemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil];

    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemsArray];
    self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f,40.0f);
    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
}    

-(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"createviews");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"showfeedbackform");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

It works for me perfectly - logging the proper choices.

As you say the `_segmentedControl` is all right - notice that I use dot notation to get segmentedControl. This might be the case since when you're not using dot notation - you're not calling the getter.

**Edit**

To sum up a little - segmentedControl from your .h file is redundant - it's just another `UISegmentedControl`. Your property can be referenced by dot notation - `self.segmentedControl`. Or by synthesized name (made by default) `_segmentedControl`.

So what you're doing is referencing to this .h object when initializing and adding your `UISegmentedController` but when `segmentedControlIndexChanged` is called - you change it in your property which is not even visible.

Comment: Make attention to leaks if you don't use ARC. Maybe write it in your answer. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post more code? Like full viewDidLoad and property declarations? Synthesizes?

Comment: Ok thank you. Just literally drop `UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;` from your .h file. It should help you since as Paul says it looks like your segmented control is not the same as property segmentedControl. And as I said - dot notation! :)

Comment: Oh and of course add `self.` in your `viewDidLoad:` whenever you're referencing segmentedControl

Comment: @AshishAgarwal, also drop the IBOutlet from your property declaration -- that makes no sense if you're not using IB.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a few things here:

1. Since you got a property, use `self.segmentedControl` instead of `segmentedControl`
2. With a simple change in your selector signature life is just easier:

---

```
[self.segmentedControl addTarget:self 
                          action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; // Notice the colon
```

---

```
-(void)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex])
    {
        case 0:
            [self createViews];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self showFeedbackForm];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, since id doesn't have a selectedSegmentIndex. You should change the argument type from id to UISegmentedControl*

Comment: @rdelmar It will compile just fine. You're just sending a message to an `id`. It _wouldn't_ compile if you were to access this as a property on `id`

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I always use dot notation, and didn't notice that you weren't. sender.selectedSegmentIndex won't compile.